# QGIS: Running field calculator from Python. Adding new calculated field

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I would like to add a new field to a layer, creating a new memorylayer from the existing layer. Where I create a new field using the expressions that are available to the "Field calculator" using the code below.

However this does not work, checking the output returns nothing.

```py
InnSA = 'C:/myLayer.shp'
outSA = 'C:/myNewLayer.shp'

oldLyr = QgsVectorLayer(InnSA, "SA", "ogr")
params = {'INPUT':oldLyr, 'FIELD_NAME':'Split', 'FIELD_TYPE':'0', 'FIELD_LENGTH':'2', 'FORMULA':'1 + ((@row_number - 1) % 9)', 'OUTPUT':'memory:'}
newLyr = processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', params)

writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(newLyr, outSA, 'utf-8', newLyr.crs(), driverName="ESRI Shapefile")
del(writer)
```

Checking the print output:

```py
>>> print(type(oldLyr))
<class 'qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer'>
>>> print(type(newLyr))
<class 'dict'>
```

I have used other processing tools in the exact same way (e.g. 'qgis:buffer', 'qgis.extractbyexpression')

What am I doing wrong, and are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: Show how you create `InnSA`. What do you mean by "checking the output"? Have you tried `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newLyr['OUTPUT'])`?

Comment: I am sorry, i added extra code and, tested more. Saw that i was missing ['OUTPUT']. It should of course be: `newLyr = processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', params)['OUTPUT']`